# Passing a NSString from View to another

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am trying to pass a  NSString to another view.

In my first view (is a map view) my code is:

FirstView.m file:

> ## import "FlipsideViewController.h"
>
> -(IBAction) displayDetails:(id) sender{
>
> ```
> MyLocation *ann = [_mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:([_mapView.selectedAnnotations count]-1)];
>
> FlipsideViewController *flipsideViewController;
> flipsideViewController=  [[FlipsideViewController alloc]init];
> flipsideViewController.details =ann.name;
> NSLog(@"ann.name:%@", ann.name);
> NSLog(@"details:%@", flipsideViewController.details);
>
> FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"details" bundle:nil];
>     controller.delegate = self;     
>   controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
>     [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
>     [controller release];
> ```
>
> }

and the NSlog print the correct string. But when I try to pass that string to my SecondViewController string called details:

In my FlipsideViewController.h is defined:

> NSString *details;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *details;

While in the FlipsideViewController.m

> @synthesize details; //and whenever I put the log, it prints the null value
>
> value:  NSLog(@"**************************detalli %@",detalli);

Where is my fault?

Comment: shows us how to pass the string to the second ViewController

Comment: Hi iArezki, NSlog return me null value in the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the secondViewController add a property, a retained property of type NSString
For adding properties please read the following

http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

Please edit this section

```
FlipsideViewController *flipsideViewController;
flipsideViewController=  [[FlipsideViewController alloc]init];
flipsideViewController.details =ann.name;
NSLog(@"ann.name:%@", ann.name);
NSLog(@"details:%@", flipsideViewController.details);

FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"details" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;     
  controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

to

```
FlipsideViewController *flipsideViewController;
flipsideViewController=  [[FlipsideViewController alloc]init];
flipsideViewController.details =ann.name;
NSLog(@"ann.name:%@", ann.name);
NSLog(@"details:%@", flipsideViewController.details);

flipsideViewController.delegate = self;     
flipsideViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:flipsideViewController animated:YES];
[flipsideViewController release];
```

Comment: In my second view I have defined the property @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *details;
Did you refer to that?

Comment: Yes, so now when you want to move to the secondview, you must first call secondView.details = annotation.name;

Comment: I Tried that but it does not work. in the first view  NSLog(@"value:%@", secondView.details); -> return the correct value BUt in the second view: NSLog(@"value:%@", details); return->null

Comment: How do you make the secondview visible? please post some code

Comment: mmm, why do you allocate a new view controller? why do you call this section 

FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"details" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;     
  controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];

Comment: because, when I touch the displayDetails function, the app go to this second view that use a "flip" animation. The transition work. there I need the "details" data n order to visualize the annotation details. Is there any problem?

Comment: Yes please check the edit i did to my answer, it should work :)

Comment: Yes, the problem was there! tx you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try this step:-
1)Firstly You  make the property   in anotherViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong ) NSString *fetchStr;
```

2) Synthesis the NSString  in anotherViewController.m

```
@synthesize fetchStr;
```

3)use in firstViewController

```
anotherViewController *avc =  [[anotherViewController alloc]init];
avc.fetchStr = ann.name;
```

and print(NSLog) the fetchStr  in anotherViewController

Comment: Thanks, It works. I didn't init the anotherViewController method!

Comment: ... but only in the first view. In the second view (where  I need the  fetchStr) the NSlog returns null ...

Comment: if you work in xcode 4.0 then use this avc.fetchStr = [ann.name retain];

Comment: I work on xcode 4.2. I try the avc.fetchStr = [ann.name retain] in the first view, but in second view the fetchStr remains the same null  :s

Comment: firstly you print the NSLog(@%@",ann.name); in firstViewController

Comment: in the first view :NSLog(@"ann.name:%@", ann.name); -> return the correct value
NSLog(@"flipsside:%@", avc.fetchStr); -> return the correct value(the same)  BUt in the second view: NSLog(@"flipsside:%@", fetchStr);  return->null

Answer (score 0):

made annotation

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) MyLocation *annotation;
```

and then pass it to another view controller.

it will work.